# Dynamic properties with ManyToOne (Laravel4/Eloquent)

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I have a pretty basic relationship wherein searches are logged and stored along with the ID of the user who performed the search.

I'm trying to output this log and display the username instead of the id.

**Search**

```
public function user()
{ 
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

**User**

```
public function searches()
{ 
    return $this->hasMany('Search');
}
```

If I then pass `Search::all();` to the view, how can I echo the username? Among many other things, I've tried:

```
@foreach($searches as $search)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $search->user->username }}</td>
        <td>{{ $search->description }}</td>
        <td>{{ $search->product }}</td>
        <td>{{ $search->group }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Your loop has `N + 1 problem`.

Your loop will execute 1 query to retrieve all of the `Searches` on the table, then another query for each `search` to retrieve the `user`. So, if you have `20 searches`, this loop would run `21` queries.

```
<td>{{ $search->user->username }}</td>
```

to avoid N + 1 problem, use the eager loading to  load the relationship.

```
Search::with('user')->all()
```

More info about N+1 problem:

```
http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I read and re-read that page of the docs last night, but the N+1 wasn't clicking. Something about your explanation **really** helped, though!